# Import real time UDP data into an excel file

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ program that can import and keep updating the real-time data which I am receiving from another server over a UDP connection into an excel or spreadsheet file present on a windows system.
I did write a program to write the data in an excel file but it does not update the real-time data.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can go about that?

Comment: Okay, sounds good. Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Please take some time to read (or refresh) [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also learn how to create a [mre] of your own attempt.

Comment: If you have a large and complex problem that you don't know how to solve, then try to divide it into smaller and less complex problems. Continue to divide each and every sub-problem until none can be further divided. Now you should have many very small and very simple problems, which you can then solve one by one. Once you put all of them together you should have a solution to the original large and complex problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Excel is programmed to be the sole program manipulating a file; it does not expect that files will be modified behind its back and therefore does not support "real time updates".

Comment: This is not true. There exists a Office 365 tool called Data Streamer, to connect a microcontroller. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-data-streamer-1d52ffce-261c-4d7b-8017-89e8ee2b806f

Comment: Which, if you read past the first paragraph, expects Excel to have the workbook open with a custom plugin installed. I bet that the custom plugin sends OLE commands to Excel.

Comment: The question didn't contain some limit that no custom plugins or Add-ons could be installed?

Comment: Fair enough. Feel free to write an answer of your own :)